# Need to add a column to a data frame. The data is in another vector and is only a subset of one original DF column for reference

Tags: r

I am a complete newbie with R and I ask for your help.

I have a data frame DF like this:

```
user      age    email        address   ...
user1     20     u1@domain    address1  ...
user2     19     u2@domain    address2  ...
user3     30     u3@domain    address3  ...
...
userm     32     um@domain    addressm ...
...
usern     xx     un@domain    address4  ...
```

I have a vector as following:

```
user1
user3
...
userm
```

I need to have the following:

```
user      age    email        address   newcol ...
user1     20     u1@domain    address1  yes    ...
user2     19     u2@domain    address2  no     ...
user3     30     u3@domain    address3  yes    ...
...
userm     32     um@domain    addressm  yes    ...
...
usern     xx     un@domain    address4  no     ...
```

In short, add a new column to DF containing  no (as default) and yes if the correspondent user is in the vector.

Any advise is appreciated, 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You basically described a perfectly good solution in your last sentence. Step 0: Create a new column of just "no"...

Comment: I'll add to @joran's helpful hint: The `%in%` operator compares one vector to another.  And a column of a data.frame is just a vector.

Comment: Fine, I'll answer!  But their advice should be plenty without the following answers :)

Comment: Thanks all. What I was missing was the `%in%`. I came here to R from Algol, Fortran, Pascal and now php.  R is a strange animal for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Joran's answer:

Assuming your `data.frame` is named df.  Make a new column in your `data.frame` called newcol:

```
df$newcol <- 'no'
```

Then change the values in newcol to 'yes' if they're `%in%` your vector (I'm assuming its named vec).

```
df$newcol[df$user %in% vec] <- 'yes'
```

You could also do this in one step using `ifelse`:

```
df$newcol <- ifelse(df$user %in% vec, 'yes', 'no')
```

Or if you wanted to get tricky you could use `merge(..., all=TRUE)`...

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the most efficient example, but it seems to work:

```
data<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("a","b","c","d","e"));
colnames(data)<-c("numbers","names");
lookup<-c("a","d","e")

data$newcol<-rep("no",dim(data)[1])

for(i in 1:length(lookup)){
store<-which(data$names==lookup[i])
data$newcol[store]<-"yes";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way...

```
DF$newcol <- 'no'
DF$newcol[DF$user %in% newVector] <- 'yes'
```

or this way

```
DF$newcol <- ifelse(DF$user %in% newVector, 'yes', no)
```

The former is suprisingly more efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
vNoYes <- c("No","Yes")# vector with new codes
idx <- (df$user %in% v)+1L# position of codes in data frame
df$newcol <- vNoYes[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use %in% function

```
df$newcol <- ifelse(df$user %in% vec, 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow typically requires you to give context and explanation in your answers if they are to be considered high quality. Please consider expanding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To detect is your values are present in the vector you could directly merge the 2 dataframe. This will particularly be helpful in case of large datasets where IFelse statements or %in% statements could take more time due to many to many matching.

eg.

```
vec=data.frame(user=vec) #converting vector to dataframe
DF <-merge(DF,unique(vec),by="user",all.x=T) #similar to left join in sql
DF$newcol<- "yes" #creating a new column having all values as yes
DF$newcol[is.na(DF$user2)]<- "no" #all the rows which were not present in the vector will be NAs in the newly joined column hence substituting these values as "no"
```